# Iterating over a collection in MongoDB for updates

Tags: mongodb, loops, collections, mongoid, moped

I'm iterating over a collection (running Moped as Ruby driver) but how to update one field for every document?

```
irb> session = Moped::Session.new(["127.0.0.1:27017"])
irb> session.use :demoapp
irb> users = session[:users]
irb> users.find.each {|u| u.update(age: rand(18..80))}
```

This doesn't update the field "age", while a simple

```
irb> users.find.each {|u| users.find(_id: u["_id"]).update(age: rand(18..80))}
```

does. But it seems not to be very effective to iterate over a collection and then look up for the id in every iteration. So how could I simplify that? I need some fast way to update millions of documents this way.

Regards,
Chris

Comment: `users.find.update_all(:$set => { age: rand(18..80) }})`?

Comment: @WiredPrairie that would set all documents to the same (randomly chosen) age.

Comment: @Leopd - true. I was concentrating on getting the syntax to be efficient and all in one call. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're treating moped more like it's mongoid.  Moped is not an ODM -- it's a low-level mongodb driver.

When you iterate `users.find` you get a collection of simple `Moped::BSON::Document` objects, which are a lot more like ruby `Hash` objects than anything else.  So when you call `update` on them, you're just updating the local one in memory and not touching the database.

Similarly

```
users.find(_id: u["_id"]).update(age: rand(18..80))
```

is not as bad as you think.  Moped compiles this to a single `update` command -- it doesn't fetch the document, modify it, and then write it back.

For ease of development, you'll probably be happier actually using mongoid, like this:

```
class User
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :age, type: Integer
end 

User.all.each do |u| 
    u.age = rand(18..80)
    u.save!
end
```

But if performance is critical, moped is faster.  You might also benchmark the official [10gen ruby driver](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/).  If you can port your code to javascript, you could run it on the mongodb server itself, which would eliminate network delays, but be careful about locking up the whole database while you do such things.

Comment: This will still fetch each document and set each document individually, won't it? It's just different syntax.

Comment: It fetches them all at once, or at least in large batches.  It writes them back one at a time.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the replies. The Moped vs Mongoid thing is: it's all about performance :) I have to update 8 millions of documents and Mongoid is 5-6 times slower than plain Moped query, even when validations are skipped it's too slow. But my first approach works fine :)

Comment: It's polite to upvote an answer if you found it useful, and accept it if it answers your question.